q->0 limits of q-special functions and q-identities - interesting examples and general principles?
There are many beautiful facts in "q-analogs world": q-special functions (e.g. basic hypergeometric series , q-identities (e.g. quantum dilogarithm related). Typically q->1 we return to classical facts. The limit q->0 is more subtle - I am not sure it always exists or gives something valuable, but in some cases it is related to crystal bases, tropical geometry, etc.
Question 1: What are some examples of non-trivial identities/special functions arising in q->0 limit ?
Question 2: Consider q-difference equations - can we make sense of the limit q->0 ? What will happen with equations and solutions ?
Question 3: What can be the limits of q-identities ? e.g.  the standard q-binomial for $ab = qba, (a+b)^n = ...  $ can one make sense of the limit q->0 ?

Here is some nice example, which I am aware of:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405309
"LU factorizations, q=0 limits, and p-adic interpretations of some q-hypergeometric orthogonal polynomials" Tom H. Koornwinder, Uri Onn
The example is quite striking.  Functions become piece-wise constant ! (Little 0-Jacobi functions). Is this a general phenomena ?

and another example - formulas 4.31-4.32 for q-Hahn polynoms.

The case $q=0$ of Askey-Wilson polynomials is also interesting. They can be written as linear combinations of five Chebyshev polynomials. See the original 1985 memoir of Askey and Wilson, or Exercise 7.26 in Gasper and Rahman, Basic hypergeometric series.

The case $q=0$ of Macdonald polynomials are Hall-Littlewood polynomials, which are very important in their own right.

Your question 3 has an easy answer. When $q=0$, the standard $q$-binomial coefficients reduce to $1$. The binomial theorem for $q$-commuting variables reduces to the obvious result
$$(a+b)^n=a^n+ba^{n-1}+\dots+b^n,$$
when $ab=0$.

@HjalmarRosengren Thanks a lot for your great comments ! May be you can turn them into answer ? Have not you seen something about q-Difference equations ? What do you think the limit should have some piece-wise constant or linear form - is general phenomena  (like in tropical geometry ) or not  ?

Since I was asked to turn my comments to an answer I will make an attempt. But these are just some examples. I think your main question "What can be the limits of $q$-identities" is too general to have a meaningful answer.
Very often, limits as $q\rightarrow 0$ make sense and lead to something more elementary than the limit $q\rightarrow 1$. For instance, the generating function for partitions of $n$ is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n)q^n=\prod_{j=1}^\infty \frac 1{1-q^j}.$$
The behaviour of this function as $q\rightarrow 1$ gives very non-trivial asymptotic properties of $p(n)$. Letting $q\rightarrow 0$ just gives the elementary fact $p(0)=1$.
Question 1: One example is the case $q=0$ of Askey-Wilson polynomials. This is worked out in the original 1985 memoir of Askey and Wilson and given as exercise 7.26 in the standard textbook Gasper and Rahman, Basic hypergeometric series. The answer is given as a linear combinations of five Chebyshev polynomials. Another example is the case $q=0$ of Macdonald polynomials, which is Hall-Littlewood polynomials. These are very important in their own right, but arguably more elementary than the limit $q\rightarrow 1$ leading to Jack polynomials.
Question 2: Look at the simplest possible case, the standard $q$-difference operator
$$(D_qf)(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(qx)}{x-qx},$$
which has as one of its eigenfunctions the $q$-exponential function
$$e_q(x)=\prod_{j=0}^\infty\frac 1{1-x q^j}.$$
Letting $q=0$ gives the fact that
$$e_0(x)=\frac 1{1-x}$$
is an eigenfunction of
$$(D_0f)(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}.$$
More complicated examples appear for instance from Macdonald's multivariable difference operators.
Question 3: Your specific example is again elementary. As you say,
$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(q;q)_n}{(q;q)_k(q;q)_{n-k}}\,b^ka^{n-k}$$
for variables satisfying $ab=qba$. Again we can put $q=0$ and obtain the obvious identity
$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^nb^ka^{n-k}$$
for variables satisfying $ab=0$.
I don't have anything to say about your question about piecewise constant limits.

Thanks a lot for the great answer ! "
More complicated examples appear for instance from Macdonald's multivariable difference operators" would you be so kind to give a reference and/or comments ?   Is something known about the statandard (q)-differential for (basic) hypergeometric function in the limit q->0 ?

@AlexanderChervov Just as in the examples I discuss above, you can just plug in $q=0$ and see what you get.
